# Visual Studio profiler too much noise in results

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, profiling, gprof, visual-studio-community

Can I restrict the results in Visual Studio? I just want to see results for code that I have written. I am following the "[500 line openGL](https://github.com/ssloy/tinyrenderer/wiki/Lesson-1:-Bresenham%E2%80%99s-Line-Drawing-Algorithm)" tutorial and I am jealous of his results in the tutorial.

```
%   cumulative   self              self     total 
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name 
 69.16      2.95     2.95  3000000     0.00     0.00  line(int, int, int, int, TGAImage&, TGAColor) 
 19.46      3.78     0.83 204000000     0.00     0.00  TGAImage::set(int, int, TGAColor) 
  8.91      4.16     0.38 207000000     0.00     0.00  TGAColor::TGAColor(TGAColor const&) 
  1.64      4.23     0.07        2    35.04    35.04  TGAColor::TGAColor(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char) 
  0.94      4.27     0.04                             TGAImage::get(int, int)
```

Here are my results below :( I am using Visual Studio Community 2017. I am using instrumentation because setup by the "Performance Wizard". If I just use "CPU Usage" I get an invalid process error. I read that this happens because my program exits too fast.

[image: My Results]

Comment: This person probably deleted all the irrelevant lines manually.

Comment: His % time adds up to 100% though, I doubt he redid all the math manually?